# Куда перед подстановкой $model нужно поместить print_r($model) в цикл, чтобы просто посмотреть, что в $model?

Tags: php, yii2

```html
<?php 
 $fotorama = \metalguardian\fotorama\Fotorama::begin(
        [
            'options' => [
                'loop' => true,
                'hash' => true,
                'ratio' => 800/600,
            ],
            'spinner' => [
                'lines' => 20,
            ],
            'tagName' => 'span',
            'useHtmlData' => false,
            'htmlOptions' => [
                'class' => 'custom-class',
                'id' => 'custom-id',
            ],
        ]
    ); 
    foreach ($model->images as $one) {
     echo  Html::img('@upload' . $one->imageUrl),(['alt'=>$one->alt]);
       } 
       $fotorama->end(); ?>
```

Comment: перед foreach  и поместите

Comment: это не работает

Answer (score 0):

Перед циклом foreach добавить `VarDumper:: dump($model);` и далее `print_r($model); 
   exit();`

Также указать namespace: `use yii\helpers\VarDumper;`